# How to retrieve the first column in a tab separated list

Tags: php, file-handling

Okay Guys, I have a list that is formatted like this:

```
Entry-no.1[tab]Description[line-break]
Entry-no.2[tab]Description[line-break]
Entry-no.3[tab]Description[line-break]
and so on...
```

I have tried everything to isolate the "Entry Column" and Create a comma seperated sheet  like this:

```
Entry-no.1,Entry-no.2,Entry-no.3,etc..
```

Here is the best Code i could come up with to do this, But it does not work :(.

```
<?php
$ls = file_get_contents("File.txt");
$newLS = "";
$index = 0;
for($i=0;$i<strlen($ls);$i++) 
{ 
if($ls[$i]=='\t'){
    $index = $i;
}
if($ls[$i]=='\n'){
    $newLS += substr($ls,0,$index); 
}
} 
echo "woot<br>";
echo $newLS;
echo "done";
?>
```

P.S. I cannot change the original layout of the file.

Comment: @snocavtoia, the line break will be handled by the str_getcsv function...that's how it knows it's the end of a record.

Comment: Accept the naive implementation. Figures. I don't know why I even bother contributing to SO anymore. What a joke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.  Documentation in line.

```
// read file into array
$array = file('File.txt');

// new array to store results
$new_array = array();

// loop through array
foreach ($array as $line) {
    // explode the line on tab. Note double quotes around \t are mandatory
    $line_array = explode("\t", $line);
    // set first element to the new array
    $new_array[] = $line_array[0];
}

// you can either use this array as is or output as comma-separate value as follows:
echo implode(',', $new_array);
```

So in summary:

- Read file into array instead of string. This takes care of line breaks for you
- Get portion of each line before tab and place in new array.
- It is important that you use double quotes around `\t` or it will be treated as a literal backslash and t.

Comment: Better hope no new columns are added to your tab-delimited CSV file.

Comment: @crush This approach would still be suitable so long as the information he is interested in still resides in first column or at a known column offset (i.e. X instead of 0).  He could however be less memory intensive by just using a string extraction rather than explode to get at the first element. In this case, I did explode for clarity of explanation.